# How do I set compile options for cmake msvc build in docker?

Tags: docker, visual-c++, cmake

I have setup a windows docker container to build msvc projects following this guide: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-msvc-in-a-docker-container-for-your-c-projects/

I'm using cmake to build, but I'm not able to set the compiler options so I can build. I need to set /Z7 (debug information format) to be able to build in the docker container, if not I get the error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error

I know this is the problem because if I manually set /Z7 in the CMakeCache.txt file, it builds.

I've tried using target compile options, add_compile_options and set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ...).

This is my CMakeLists.txt at the moment:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (ConsoleApplication1)
add_executable(ConsoleApplication1 ConsoleApplication1.cpp)
target_compile_options(ConsoleApplication1 PRIVATE /Z7 /W4)
```

The application is a default ConsoleApplication created through VS2017.

Complete error message:
Complete error message:

```
PS C:\consoleapplication1\build> cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.16299.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27030.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27030.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
CMake Error: Remove failed on file: C:/consoleapplication1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_714d8.pdb: System Error: No such file or directory
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/BuildTools/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/consoleapplication1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"C:/BuildTools/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_714d8.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0"
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Build started 7/4/2019 1:01:26 PM.
    Project "C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_714d8.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    PrepareForBuild:
      Creating directory "cmTC_714d8.dir\Debug\".
      Creating directory "C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".
      Creating directory "cmTC_714d8.dir\Debug\cmTC_714d8.tlog\".
    InitializeBuildStatus:
      Creating "cmTC_714d8.dir\Debug\cmTC_714d8.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
    ClCompile:
      C:\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_714d8.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_714d8.dir\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
      Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27030.1 for x86
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

      cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_714d8.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_714d8.dir\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c

      testCCompiler.c
    Link:
      C:\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_714d8.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:/consoleapplication1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_714d8.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/consoleapplication1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_714d8.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH  /machine:X86 cmTC_714d8.dir\Debug\testCCompiler.obj
    LINK : fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23) '(0x000006E7)' [C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_714d8.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_714d8.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_714d8.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
    (Link target) ->
      LINK : fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23) '(0x000006E7)' [C:\consoleapplication1\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_714d8.vcxproj]

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:01.55




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/consoleapplication1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/consoleapplication1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Have anyone been able to make this work: docker windows containers, cmake, msvc? I would be very interested in seeing the CMakeLists.txt you then have used.

edit: added CMakeLists.txt and full error output

Comment: Setting `/Z7` via compiler options seems to be a proper way. Probably, something else is wrong with you code, but without viewing this code we cannot help you. Please, prepare [mcve].

Comment: Updated my question with my current CMakeLists.txt, the program I try to compile is just a default console application.

Comment: Please, show **exact error message** too (it should include the target which is built, filename and other related info).

Comment: Full error output added. As you see it use /Zi instead of /Z7 when building. If I change this manually in the CMakeCache.txt file it builds without errors.

Comment: I found this bug report which explains my problem: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/829
But I still don't understand why I can't override the compiler settings used by cmake.

Comment: As you can see in the configuration log, the error is not about compiling your executable. The error is about **compiler check**. This check is performed **immediately** at `project()` call, so everything after this call is *unrelated*. A compiler is detected using CMake internal scripts and information provided by a system, so exactly they are responsible for fail.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to override the settings at that time? If I change "Debug Information Format" in the CMakeCache.txt after a failed build, it builds without error. Its also one of the workarounds in the link I gave, but then directly in the project properties which isn't an option for me.

Comment: "so there is no way to override the settings at that time?" - You may override this settings, but not with a "normal" programming in `CMakeLists.txt`. Setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED`, as described in your answer, is one of the ways for overcome the problem. It could be also other ways, but all of them are ... hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tsyvarev noticed the problem is the compiler checking and not the compiling of my code, and its related to building in a bind mount as mentioned here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/829#issuecomment-397149736

Since setting the 'Debug Information Format' in the project file (workaround B in link) is no solution for me I found a workaround to skip the compiler check. This is the CMakeLists.txt that works for me.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE)
project (ConsoleApplication1)
add_executable(ConsoleApplication1 ConsoleApplication1.cpp)
target_compile_options(ConsoleApplication1 PRIVATE /Z7 /W4)
```

I'm not sure if setting COMPILER_FORCED has side effects, but at least it allows me to build in the docker container.

Here is also a bug reported to MS on this problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/607325/lnk1318-unexpected-pdb-error-when-building-from-a.html